# Click on login button using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm having trouble performing a click operation on a website. I'm getting a error message `NoSuchElementException`, but I'm not sure why because I got the class name from the site.

What am I missing?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


s = Service('C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe')


chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chromeOptions)

list_data = []

def initialize_browser():
   driver.get("https://virtualracingschool.appspot.com/#/Home")
   print("starting_Driver")
   click_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "white-text")
   driver.implicitly_wait(15)
   click_button.click()

initialize_browser()
```

Site & Code:

[image: []]

I tried referencing some documents from the selenium site and it mentions for a format

```
<p class="content">Site content goes here.</p>`
```

write the code:

```
content = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'content')`
```

I felt like I did this properly but my site has

```
<a class="white-text" style="" ...>
    <span>Login</span>
</a>
```

format. Is the `<a>` and `"style"` element hindering my code?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below XPath expression:

`//span[text()='Login']`

Your code should look like this:

`click_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Login']")`

Below is the inspect element by this XPath for your reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per your code trials:

```
click_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "white-text")
```

`By.CLASS_NAME, "white-text"` identifies four elements within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp):

[image: white-text]

Hence you see the see the error.

---

### Solution

To click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://virtualracingschool.appspot.com/#/Home')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.white-text > span"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://virtualracingschool.appspot.com/#/Home')  
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='white-text']//span"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: virtualracingschool]